# "Cannot find module 'jsreport-core' azure" error after publishing ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, pdf-generation, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, jsreport

How to convert html to pdf in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0? Have already tried with pdf random but it is throwing error post publishing in Azure. The error says

> Cannot find module 'jsreport-core' azure.

Following is the code used:

```
module.exports = function (callback, html) { 

    var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')()

    jsreport.init().then(function () { 
        return jsreport.render({ 
            template: { 
                content: newHtml, 
                engine: 'jsrender', 
                recipe: 'phantom-pdf',

            } 
        }).then(function (resp) { 
            callback(null, resp.content.toJSON().data); 
        }); 
    }).catch(function (e) { 
        callback(e, null); 
    }) 
};
```

This code is working fine when not published in Azure portal. After publishing it is throwing the above highlighted error. Some of the steps already taken are: Added the node.exe to the root folder. Somehow it is not able to load the js libraries(jsreport-core,jsreport-core,phantom-pdf) after being deployed.

Comment: Hi @SharadhaR, could you please post your code? It would then be easier to help you out!

Comment: From Review: Please add your source code and replace some of your tags with the ".netcore" tag.

Comment: added source code

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is yet to be implemented with asp.net core 2.0.